# Few Oracle related questions, difference between Oracle client and ODAC

Tags: .net, oracle

what I want is to manage Oracle programmatically from a .NET C# project. I have few thoughts so please tell me if I'm correct. 
As far as I know I have to use the standard ADO.NET api. Additionally, I need to use a specific provider. I can use either the .NET default oracle client (which is now deprecated) or the Oracle ODP.NET provider.

I'm using Oracle Express client, is ODP.NET included in this client ? 
Also what is the difference between the Oracle client and ODAC ? Why is ODAC creating another home directory ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the ODP.net drivers were included by browsing into your oracle client directory and looking for an "odp.net" folder. If you've got assemblies in a bin folder in there, then ODP.net was installed.

The ODAC installer wants to install a new Oracle home because it includes another copy of the Oracle Instant Client. You should be able to just tell it to not do that by picking an existing Oracle home during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know .NET oracle client (System.Data.OracleClient) is now  deprecated and it is recommended to use ODAC instead:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx

Our team had numerouse problems with .NET default oracle provider so we have moved to ODAC.
As for Oracle Express you have no limitations on installing and using ODAC. I recommend you to install the latest version of ODAC:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html